# Ruby multidimensional array

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

Maybe it's just my lack of abilities to find stuff here that is the problem, but I can't find anything about how to create multidimensional arrays in Ruby.

Could someone please give me an example on how to do it?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Strictly speaking it is not possible to create multi dimensional arrays in Ruby. But it is possible to put an array in another array, which is almost the same as a multi dimensional array.

This is how you could create a 2D array in Ruby:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

---

As stated in the comments, you could also use [NArray](http://masa16.github.io/narray/) which is a Ruby numerical array library:

```
require 'narray'
b = NArray[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]
```

---

Use `a[i][j]` to access the elements of the array. Basically `a[i]` returns the 'sub array' stored on position `i` of `a` and thus `a[i][j]` returns element number `j` from the array that is stored on position `i`.

Comment: As an alternative (for scientific calculations/dense data), consider NArray or encoding method.

Comment: It's important to note the syntax for accessing this is `a[1][2][1]` and not `a[1,2,1]` as some might expect.

Comment: @veger how do i get the values from that array?

Comment: @andkjaer: already mentioned by [tadman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman), but I extended my answer with some extra details on the workings of it.

Comment: This is extensible to multi dimensional arrays > dim 2. E.g. my3Darray=[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[['a','b','c'],['d','e','fgh']]]; puts my3Darray[1][1][2][1]

Comment: Try this class: [Matrix](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html), and see this very helpful article: [Manipulating Structured Data in Ruby](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=26943) by Hal Fulton.

Comment: That class Matrix is not so great if you ever need to change a value in it. The entries are immutable

Comment: what does `a[i][]` return?

Comment: Is there a way to check if an item is in one specific location throughout each array?  For example, if I have [['bob', 'male', '28'],['todd', 'male', '22'], ['sue', 'female', '24']] and I want to see if 'bob' is included within any of the first columns.  Would I need to iterate through each and check?

Answer (score 23):

you can pass a block to `Array.new`

```
Array.new(n) {Array.new(n,default_value)}
```

the value that returns the block will be the value of each index of the first array,

so..

```
Array.new(2) {Array.new(2,5)} #=> [[5,5],[5,5]]
```

and you can access this array using `array[x][y]`

also for second Array instantiation, you can pass a block as default value too. so

```
Array.new(2) { Array.new(3) { |index| index ** 2} } #=> [[0, 1, 4], [0, 1, 4]]
```

Comment: You don't need to specify the size of the arrays when initializing this way.  myArray = Array.new{Array.new} works fine to initialize an empty array that's ready to have arrays pushed into it.

Comment: The example given by @emery is dangerous: one cannot index into such an array: `(Array.new{Array.new})[2][2] = :value  # => NoMethodError: undefined method '[]=' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 11):

Just a clarification:

```
arr = Array.new(2) {Array.new(2,5)} #=> [[5,5],[5,5]]
```

is not at all the same as:

```
arr = Array.new(2, Array.new(2, 5))
```

in the later case, try:

```
arr[0][0] = 99
```

and this is what you got:

```
[[99,5], [99,5]]
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to initialize multi array (size of 2).
All the another answers show examples with a default value.

Declare each of sub-array (you can do it in a runtime):

```ruby
multi = []
multi[0] = []
multi[1] = []
```

or declare size of a parent array when initializing:

```
multi = Array.new(2) { Array.new }
```

Usage example:

```
multi[0][0] = 'a'
multi[0][1] = 'b'
multi[1][0] = 'c'
multi[1][1] = 'd'

p multi # [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]
p multi[1][0] # "c"
```

So you can wrap the first way and use it like this:

```
@multi = []
def multi(x, y, value)
  @multi[x] ||= []
  @multi[x][y] = value
end

multi(0, 0, 'a')
multi(0, 1, 'b')
multi(1, 0, 'c')
multi(1, 1, 'd')

p @multi # [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]
p @multi[1][0] # "c"
```

Answer (score 3):

The method given above don't works.

```
n = 10
arr = Array.new(n, Array.new(n, Array.new(n,0.0))) 
arr[0][1][2] += 1
puts arr[0][2][2]
```

is equivalent to

```
n = 10
a = Array.new(n,0.0)
b = Array.new(n,a)
arr = Array.new(n, b) 
arr[0][1][2] += 1
puts arr[0][2][2]
```

and will print 1.0, not 0.0, because we are modifiyng array a and printing the element of array a.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is much quicker than the block method given above:

```
arr = Array.new(n, Array.new(n, Array.new(n,0.0))) 

arr[0][1][2] += 1
```

Comment: Example from @Kri-ban is incorrect. The nested arrays are not all new objects but shared across cells, e.g: `a = Array.new(2, Array.new(2, 0.0)); a[0][1] = 5; a # => [[0.0, 5], [0.0, 5]]` the `5` appears at indices `[0][1]` and `[1][1]` even though it was only set once.

Answer (score 1):

I had to reproduce PHP-style multidimensional array in Ruby recently. Here is what I did:

```
# Produce PHP-style multidimensional array.
#
# Example
#
# arr = Marray.new
#
# arr[1][2][3] = "foo"
# => "foo"
#
# arr[1][2][3]
# => "foo"

class Marray < Array
  def [](i)
    super.nil? ? self[i] = Marray.new : super
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can simulate your multidimensional Array with a Hash. The Hash-key can by any Ruby object, so you could also take an array.

Example:

```
marray = {}
p marray[[1,2]]   #-> nil
marray[[1,2]] = :a
p marray[[1,2]]   #-> :a
```

Based on this idea you could define a new class.

Just a quick scenario:

```
=begin rdoc
Define a multidimensional array.

The keys must be Fixnum.

The following features from Array are not supported:
* negative keys (Like Array[-1])
* No methods <<, each, ...
=end
class MArray
  INFINITY = Float::INFINITY
=begin rdoc
=end
  def initialize(dimensions=2, *limits)
    @dimensions = dimensions
    raise ArgumentError if limits.size > dimensions
    @limits = []
    0.upto(@dimensions-1){|i|
      @limits << (limits[i] || INFINITY)
    }
    @content = {}
  end
  attr_reader :dimensions
  attr_reader :limits
=begin rdoc
=end
  def checkkeys(keys)
    raise ArgumentError, "Additional key values for %i-dimensional Array" % @dimensions if keys.size > @dimensions
    raise ArgumentError, "Missing key values for %i-dimensional Array" % @dimensions if keys.size != @dimensions
    raise ArgumentError, "No keys given" if keys.size == 0
    keys.each_with_index{|key,i|
      raise ArgumentError, "Exceeded limit for %i dimension" % (i+1) if key > @limits[i]
      raise ArgumentError, "Only positive numbers allowed" if key < 1

    }
  end
  def[]=(*keys)
    data = keys.pop
    checkkeys(keys)
    @content[keys] = data
  end
  def[](*keys)
    checkkeys(keys)
    @content[keys]
  end
end
```

This can be used as:

```
arr = MArray.new()
arr[1,1] = 3
arr[2,2] = 3
```

If you need a predefined matrix 2x2 you can use it as:

```
arr = MArray.new(2,2,2)
arr[1,1] = 3
arr[2,2] = 3
#~ arr[3,2] = 3  #Exceeded limit for 1 dimension (ArgumentError)
```

I could imagine how to handle commands like `<<` or `each` in a two-dimensional array, but not in multidimensional ones.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to remember that the array is an object in ruby, and objects are not (by default) created simply by naming them or naming a the object reference.  Here is a routine for creating a 3 dimension array and dumping it to the screen for verification:

```
def Create3DimensionArray(x, y, z, default)
    n = 0                       # verification code only
    ar = Array.new(x)
    for i in 0...x
        ar[i] = Array.new(y)
        for j in 0...y
            ar[i][j] = Array.new(z, default)
            for k in 0...z      # verification code only
                ar[i][j][k] = n # verification code only
                n += 1          # verification code only
            end                 # verification code only
        end
    end
    return ar
end

# Create sample and verify
ar = Create3DimensionArray(3, 7, 10, 0)

for x in ar
    puts "||"
    for y in x
        puts "|"
        for z in y
            printf "%d ", z
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Better verification code: <pre>for x in 0...ar.length
 for y in 0...ar[x].length
  for z in 0...ar[x][y].length
   printf "%3d ", ar[x][y][z]
  end
  puts "|"
 end
 puts "--"
end
</pre>

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of a 3D array class in ruby, in this case the default value is 0

```
class Array3
 def initialize
   @store = [[[]]]
 end

 def [](a,b,c)
  if @store[a]==nil ||
    @store[a][b]==nil ||
    @store[a][b][c]==nil
   return 0
  else
   return @store[a][b][c]
  end
 end

 def []=(a,b,c,x)
  @store[a] = [[]] if @store[a]==nil
  @store[a][b] = [] if @store[a][b]==nil
  @store[a][b][c] = x
 end
end


array = Array3.new
array[1,2,3] = 4
puts array[1,2,3] # => 4
puts array[1,1,1] # => 0
```