# Populating two dimensional array with Hash Keys for similar Values

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby. I have a (already sorted) hash with the following values. I want to put the keys of these in multidimensional array on the basis of there values. So, for example

For

```
VALUES - KEYS 
acemrs - a
acemrs - b

acrs - c
acrs - d
acrs - e

aeoopstt - f

for - g

foru -h
```

I am looking for an array like [ [a,b] , [c,d,e] , [f] , [g] , [h] ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hash = {'a'=>'acemrs','b'=>'acemrs','c'=>'acrs','d'=>'acrs','e'=>'acrs','f'=>'aeoopstt','g'=>'for','h'=>'foru'}
new_hash = {}

hash.each_pair do |key, value|
  (new_hash[value] ||= []) << key
end

array = new_hash.values
```

We use the previous hash `values` as `keys` for the new hash. If undefined, we create a new array for each new `keys` with `new_hash[value] ||= []` then just push all keys in the new hash with `<< key`. The new hash will be something like

```
{"aeoopstt"=>["f"], "for"=>["g"], "acemrs"=>["b", "a"], "acrs"=>["e", "d", "c"], "foru"=>["h"]}
```

At the end, you just want those values so `new_hash.values` and you are done.

[Hash API](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html).

Comment: Nice style. I'd probably explain the hash iteration block, though, since he's new to ruby ;)

Comment: Thank you Adam, added some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
hash.group_by{|k, v| v}.values.map(&:first)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just working off this question: [Ruby multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014052/ruby-multidimensional-array)

You can use  [NArray](http://narray.rubyforge.org/),  a Ruby numerical array library:

```
require 'narray'

array = NArray[  [a,b] , [c,d,e] , [f] , [g] , [h] ]
```

then

`array[1][2]` would return 'b', and `array[2][3]` would return 'e', et c.