# How to select adjacent array value if adjacent is empty with ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to figure out how to select an array value if it is adjacent to a filled array value and is empty.

So let's say the grid the array references is laid out like so.

```
 a1,a2,a3,
 b1,b2,b3,
 c1,c2,c3
```

If a1 holds an X the grid will now look like so.

```
 X,a2,a3,
 b1,b2,b3,
 c1,c2,c3
```

I want the method to be able to find the adjacent array values, in this case, a2, b1 and b2.

But in this next case where O holds the center value.

```
 X,a2,a3,
 b1,O,b3,
 c1,c2,c3
```

...the method would select a2, b1

Can anyone provide a solution or a tip?

This is a simple tic-tac-toe grid

Here is a look at the class where the grid lives.

```
class Board
attr_reader :grid

def initialize(cell_value = " ")
  @grid = {
    a1: cell_value, a2: cell_value, a3: cell_value,
    b1: cell_value, b2: cell_value, b3: cell_value,
    c1: cell_value, c2: cell_value, c3: cell_value
  }
end

def printgrid
  board = "\n"
  board << "a #{@grid[:a1]}|#{@grid[:a2]}|#{@grid[:a3]} \n"
  board << "----------\n"
  board << "b #{@grid[:b1]}|#{@grid[:b2]}|#{@grid[:b3]} \n"
  board << "----------\n"
  board << "c #{@grid[:c1]}|#{@grid[:c2]}|#{@grid[:c3]} \n"
  board << "----------\n"
  board << "  1 2 3\n"
end

def space_taken?(cell_location)
  cell_value = cell_location
  @grid[cell_value] != " "
end
end
```

Comment: What is the structure of the grid? Is it 2D? How is it related to an array? What is a "center value"?

Comment: how on earth does someone get 11000 points on a 2year account?

Comment: While Stefan's method below will work, your most fundamental problem here is that you are using a 1D data structure to represent a 2D situation. Make grid a 2D structure and the whole problem becomes a lot easier to understand.

Comment: I'd also suggest doing this on paper or something first - getting too caught up in the code may well be what led you to have this problem.

Comment: @BenParsons I'm a noob at ruby. I've been building this game for months. I didn't even know to ask the question "should this be a 2d structure"

Comment: @BenParsons Having a 1D array in this kind of situations is not necessarily bad. It is possible to play around with modulo 3. The rows and the columns will correspond to the quotient and the remainder.

Comment: @sawa, there are all kinds of ways to implement tic tac toe, you're correct - but for ease of understanding (which is an unasked question admittedly), I really feel having a 2D array would be most suitable. In this way we would do away with letters in the grid, and allow us to address cells relative to any other - adjacent values become easy to find.

Comment: @ben true, but dealing with special cases (cells outside the 3×3 grid) can be complicated, too.

Comment: I would love some comments from the "experienced" gents who found it necessary to downvote this noobs question without, of course, providing any code to support their multidimensional array in ruby recommendations...to this post...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014052/ruby-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a method to determine if a cell is next to an `X`:

```
def next_to_x?(cell_location)
  case cell_location
  when :a1
    @grid[:a2] == 'X' or @grid[:b1] == 'X' or @grid[:b2] == 'X'
  when :a2
    @grid[:a1] == 'X' or @grid[:a3] == 'X' or @grid[:b1] == 'X' or @grid[:b2] == 'X' or @grid[:b3] == 'X'
  # ...
  end
end
```

Then, to find all cells that are both empty and next to an `X`:

```
[:a1, :a2, :a3, :b1, :b2, :b3, :c1, :c2, :c3].find_all { |cell_location|
  !space_taken(cell_location) and next_to_x?(cell_location)
}
```

Comment: thank you I think I'll try this answer to my original question.