# Build a multidimensional array from its shape

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array, shapes

I would like to build a *multidimensional array* from its **shape**.
To do so, I wrote this method:

```
def build_array(*shape)
  arr = shape[0..-2].reverse.inject(Array.new(shape.last)) do |a, size|
    Array.new(size, a)
  end
end
```

Example:

```
arr = build_array(2, 8)
=> [[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil],
    [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]]
```

However, its generated sub-arrays seems to be a same object:

```
arr.each do |sub|
  puts sub.object_id
end
70179850332980
70179850332980
```

How could we fix the method in order to have a clean generated array? Thanks.

Comment: That's not a multidimensional array, that's an array-of-arrays.

Comment: I'm pretty confident those are the same thing in ruby

Comment: @mu-is-too-short: Interesting. What difference is there between these two concepts?

Comment: @hkparker: No they're not. `[[0],[1,1]]` is perfectly fine as an array-of-arrays but it is certainly not structured like a two dimensional array. With a multidimensional array, you can slice it along any dimension (i.e. extract a row or a column as an array), an array-of-arrays doesn't let you do that without extra work. You can also ask an multidimensional array what its dimensions are, an array-of-arrays requires you to open it up and manually see what the dimensions are. Compare `Matrix` from the standard library with a raw array-of-arrays to see the difference.

Comment: That makes sense, I don't believe there is such a thing in the ruby standard library however, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014052/ruby-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try:

```
def build_array(*shape)
  return if shape.empty?
  Array.new(shape.shift) { build_array *shape }
end
```

Comment: Gotta love this solution!

Comment: Tested both and can confirm unique object ids for this solution

Comment: nice use of the constructor... always forget about that!

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
def build(*shape)
  return nil if shape.empty?

  result = []
  count = shape.shift
  count.times do |i|
    result << build(*shape)
  end

  result
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
def build_array(*shape)
  arr = shape[0..-2].reverse.inject(Array.new(shape.last)) do |a, size|
    Array.new(size) { a.clone }
  end
end
```