# How do you get a multidimensional array?

Tags: ruby

I wanted to know how to create a dimensional array from this string:

```
str = "1 for R3, 2 for R7, 3 for R10, 5 for R14.50"
```

I want to get this:

```
[[1, 3][2, 7][3, 10][5, 14.50]]
```

This is my code:

```
remove = str.gsub! ' for R', ' '
arr = remove.split ' ,'
arr.each do |x|
  puts x.split('R')
end
```

and this is the results I get:

```
1 3
2 7
3 10
5 14.50
```

It does not give the desired result, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014052/ruby-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Your desired output is not valid Ruby expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
str.scan(/([\d.]+) for R([\d.]+)/)
# => [["1", "3"], ["2", "7"], ["3", "10"], ["5", "14.50"]]

str.scan(/([\d.]+) for R([\d.]+)/)
.map{|a| a.map{|s| s.to_i == s.to_f ? s.to_i : s.to_f}}
# => [[1, 3], [2, 7], [3, 10], [5, 14.5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str.scan(/[\d.]+/).each_slice(2).to_a
  #=> [["1", "3"], ["2", "7"], ["3", "10"], ["5", "14.50"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start `irb` session and check what is going on! So first of all, open shell and start `irb` interactive ruby interpreter.

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0>
```

Now, let's execute the code line by line and see if something is going not as we suspect.

```
irb(main):001:0> str = "1 for R3, 2 for R7, 3 for R10, 5 for R14.50"
=> "1 for R3, 2 for R7, 3 for R10, 5 for R14.50"

irb(main):002:0> remove = str.gsub! ' for R', ' '
=> "1 3, 2 7, 3 10, 5 14.50"

irb(main):003:0> arr = remove.split ' ,'
=> ["1 3, 2 7, 3 10, 5 14.50"]
```

Looks like problem is here, it returned an array with only one element instead of four. Let's try to split by different string `', '` instead of `' ,'`.

```
irb(main):004:0> arr = remove.split ', '
=> ["1 3", "2 7", "3 10", "5 14.50"]
```

Looks better! Now last part to split every array element by space.

```
irb(main):005:0> arr.map do |x|
irb(main):006:1* x.split ' '
irb(main):007:1> end
=> [["1", "3"], ["2", "7"], ["3", "10"], ["5", "14.50"]]
```

The last thing you may want to do is to convert the strings like `"1"` to numbers using `.to_i` method, but I'm leaving this up to you.

In summary `irb` is really nice tool when you want to check on how something is working.

Answer (score 0):

Short non-regex version:

```
x = "1 for R3, 2 for R7, 3 for R10, 5 for R14.50"

p x.split(', ').map{|x| x.split ' for R' } #=> [["1", "3"], ["2", "7"], ["3", "10"], ["5", "14.50"]]
```