# Multidimensional ruby array: Is it possible to define the []-operator with more than one argument?

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

I want to implement a table datastructure. Maybe you can recommend a better alternative, but as Ruby doesn't provide built-in support for multidimensional arrays, the nearest solution is using a Hash and an Array as index

```
pseudoTable = Hash.new
pseudoTable[[0,"id"]] = 23
pseudoTable[[0,"name"]] = "Hans"
```

Now I tried the following

```
class MyTable
  attr_accessor :id, :table_hash
  def [](a,b)
    @table_hash[[a,b]]
  end
end
```

So, isn't it possible in Ruby to give two arguments to `def []()` ?

If not, can you recommend another approach (a built-in datastructure than Hash, etc. better suited) to implement a table capable of dynamic extension and bonus points for being sequentially iterable?

Comment: _"isn't it possible in Ruby to give two arguments to def []()?"_ – you just did it. Is there an error or something?

Comment: I think that this is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014052/ruby-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the behavior you're looking for?

```
class MyTable
  def initialize()
    @table = Hash.new
  end

  def [](a, b)
    return nil if @table[a].nil?
    @table[a][b]
  end

  def []=(a, b, c)
    @table[a] ||= {}
    @table[a][b] = c
  end
end
```

usage:

```
2.4.1 :038 > a = MyTable.new
 => #<MyTable:0x007faf6f9161c8 @table={}>
2.4.1 :039 > a[0,0]
 => nil
2.4.1 :040 > a[0,0] = 1
 => 1
2.4.1 :041 > a[0,0]
 => 1
```

I'm pretty confident there are better ways to do this, and this solution might contain some bugs, but hopefully it demonstrates how to define and use multi-argument `[]` and `[]=` methods.

Comment: I think this is a great general example and will help a lot of people.

Comment: Are there other built-in data-structures than Hashes that might be suited better and that allow sequential iteration?

Comment: Good answer, note that you can use `dig` in recent versions of ruby to bypass that test for nil in the `[]` method... `def[](a,b);@table.dig(a, b);end`

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [ruby-numo library](http://ruby-numo.github.io/narray/)

```
apt install -y git ruby gcc ruby-dev rake make
gem install specific_install
gem specific_install https://github.com/ruby-numo/narray.git

irb
```

---

```
arr = Numo::Narray[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]

 => Numo::Int32#shape=[3,3]
[[1, 0, 0],
 [1, 2, 0],
 [1, 2, 3]]

arr[0, 0]
 => 1

arr[0, 1]
 => 0

arr[0, 2]
 => 0

arr[0, 3]
IndexError: index=3 out of shape[1]=3
```

You can learn more detailed documentation [there](http://ruby-numo.github.io/narray/narray/Numo/NArray.html)

Answer (score 1):

What you did would work fine, the trouble is that `@table_hash` is not recognised as a hash.  You need to initialize it as such.

```
class MyTable
  attr_accessor :id, :table_hash

  def initialize(*args)
    @table_hash = Hash.new
    super
  end

  def [](a,b)
    @table_hash[[a,b]]
  end
end
```

Comment: You're correct. No error.

I really don't know what went wrong. Sorry for having you bothered with such a slip of mine. I'm sure that I have initialized it as Hash.new.

Thanks for your answers Stefan and Steve!

Yours sincerely,

von Spotz